# Book for an appointment an hour later

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Say Susan has arranged an appointment for us some time in the past. The appointment was for 1 hour later. Is it correct to say:

> Susan booked us in for an appointment an hour later with a specialist to install the protector.

I couldn't decide if it means the appointment is 1 hour later or Susan took 1 hour to make an appointment?

Comment: Did Susan just make the appointment now, or are you talking about something in the past?

Comment: Hi @gotube something in the past.

Answer (score 1):

An hour later than what?

If you mean that, for example, it's now 10am and the appointment is for 11, it's *an hour from now* or *in an hour's time.*

We would only use *an hour later* with reference to some other time, for example "The bus got in at 9.30 and the appointment was for an hour later." (10.30.)

Comment: Would adding "that is" to @FlyingPenguin's sentence suffice? "Susan booked us in for an appointment that is an hour later." Would an hour later from now be implied or it's important to explicitly state it?

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of "from now" and it indeed improves clarity! I have edited the example sentence. I reckon "from now" applies to present tense. How can I phrase it if is to narrate a past event without reference to a specific time?

Comment: Responding to your amended passage - commonsense would imply that the appointment was for an hour after the time of booking. Otherwise _an hour later_ would be placed at the beginning of the sentence, or mention would be made of the fact that it took her an hour to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is ambiguous. Depending on the surrounding context, it could mean either:

Susan booked us in for an appointment an hour later with a specialist to install the protector.

> **An hour later**, Susan booked us in for an appointment.

OR

> Susan books us in for an appointment **an hour from then**.